# How to divide PHP decimal numbers?

Tags: php, numbers, decimal

I have this line of code:

```
$kaina =  $_POST["price"];
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lb.lt/lb_buhalteriniai_euro_ir_uzsienio_valiutu_santykiai?tp=LT&rs=&dte='.$data.'&ccy=USD');
$ret = $html->find('td', 6);

echo $ret . "</br>";

$aaa = str_replace(",",".",$ret);
// $aaa = "1.0900";

echo $aaa. "</br>";
echo bcdiv($kaina, $aaa,  4);
```

So I have a parser which gets data from particular website. $ret echos 1,0962, so I changed , to . to get me able to divide and add decimals. In the last line if I divide $kaina and $aaa nothing shows up, but if I change $aaa to string like "1.0900" everything works, can't get it why.

Comment: instead of echoing your result, you should use var_dump() to debug what is going on. Then you will not have any "nothing shows up", e.g. it also shows you if a value is null, or false, or something like that. Back to topic: you should probably have a look at [type casting and type juggling](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Please post the result of `echo "$kaina / $aaa = " . bcdiv($kaina, $aaa,  4);`

Comment: print_r outputs 1.0962NULL and var dump - string(15) "1.0962" NULL, but it echos 1.0962

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what does var_dump/print_r shows from $aaa variable?

Then, try to parse string into numbers with [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) functions, and then divide. You may wish then to round numbers with [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) / [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) functions.
Or try something like that:

```
bcdiv((string)$var1, (string)$var2, (string)$precision);
```